# I am thinking about using automapper to translate a typed dataset to a generic List of objects

Tags: generics, dataset, automapper, strongly-typed-dataset, generic-list

Actually I want to return a generic list of certain types bases on a typed dataset. I know the type in my method, so I can use some kind of generic code to call to do the translation.

So currently my methods return typed datasets, but they should return generic lists.
I am thinking about using Automapper, but the time (because of upcoming holidays) lacks to create some prototypes. So I would really like to read about your experiences.

Any other suggestions on how to realize my goal are very welcome. This way I might learn of an even better way to complete my task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:
http://house9.blogspot.com/2010/11/automapper-datatable-to-list.html

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Person>();

IList<Person> people = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<Person>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```